# Task Manager Default GPU Graphs, show Compute in Summary

Tags: windows

I use a lot of compute workloads and would like to monitor basic/recent history in Task Manager. I can select "Compute 0/1" as a graph manually for usage there, (or 3D/Decode, etc.). But;

1. Is there a way to save which graphs are displayed each time Task Manager is opened?
2. Is there a way to have the "Compute" usage shown in the summary graph, rather than "3D"?

Searching Regedit for "Compute" or "3D" or "GPU" elicits too many results.